# The file accepts answer not print

Tags: python-2.7, file, statements

my English and Python knowledge is very low.....
so, my question , Write a version of a palindrome recogniser that accepts a file name from the user, reads each line, and prints the line to the screen if it is a palindrome.

my code:

```
that is was i write to the textfile: "anna" "keek" "toot" "poop" "eguzki"

def palindrome():
    with open('home/me/pytho/textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
             for i in f:
                if i == i[:-1]:
                    new = i
             print new

palindrome()
```

But i come nothing...can please answer with simple  word's ,because my code it is not gut , Thanks !

Comment: would you like to check every comma seperated word is palindrome or not? i mean read the file and checks for plaindormity of seperate words, anna, keek, poop etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! , not , i will not check the comma.. i have to try in loop use split() , bat i don't know how do it.....

Comment: I have to write: for i in f.split(","):      and i come ,  AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: of course, file object has no split atrributes. you've to read it first. under your `with open` line, add `words =  f.readlines()`.

Comment: Thanks , but all abode similar ... , i have to change in loop the name , for i in words , but change nothing.... i have before to look more information about file , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_methods.htm

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what to do it.... this is my first file exercise.....

Comment: ok, look at my answer. maybe it will help you.

Comment: @marmeladze  what to do [0] ??

Answer (score 1):

*example text file*

```
$ cat ex.txt 
"anna", "keek", "toot", "poop", "eguzki"
```

*python code*

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]

with open('ex.txt') as f:
    words = f.readlines()[0].split(", ")
    for word in words:
        print word, "palindrome" if is_palindrome(word) else "not palindrome"
```

executing code.

```
$ python palindrome.py 
"anna" palindrome
"keek" palindrome
"toot" palindrome
"poop" palindrome
"eguzki" not palindrome
```

Comment: Thanks for your work , but in my idle console i come :                           anna keek toot poop eguzki
not palindrome

Comment: sorryyyyyyy , bevor i have the string from my text loss .... , you answer ist gut!!     "anna" palindrome
"keek" palindrome
"toot" palindrome
"poop" palindrome
"eguzki"
not palindrome

Comment: First very Thanks for you answer and your work! , I have a question .... what to do [0]

Comment: with `readlines()` it reads whole file (if there is no linebreaks, '\n') into the list.

Comment: no zeroth (first) element of the resulting list. just print `f.readlines()` to see what is happening

Comment: I have to write print f.readlines() under with...... and i come  ['"anna", "keek", "toot", "poop", "eguzki"\n', '\n', '\n']     , here i have to read that "Text files are structured as a sequence of lines, where each line includes a sequence of characters. This is what you know as code or syntax. "     http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python